# if $f(0) = 0$ is it true that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: [ f(x)<x \implies f'(x)\leq 1]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is a question from my calculus book in high school.

$f(x)$ is a function and $f(0) = 0$

Is it true that $\forall x: f(x) \le x \iff f'(x) \le 1$

----edit----

what can we say about two sides of the equivalency?

1)$\forall x: f(x) \le x \implies f'(x) \le 1$

2)$\forall x: f'(x) \le 1 \implies f(x) \le x $

Comment: are two sides of the implication false?

Comment: Yes for the other side consider counterexample, $f(x) = 100$. To get a better idea take a graph paper and plot $y=x$, then draw some function that stays below this line and see if there should be any restriction on its slope.

Comment: @across the function $f(x) = 100$ does not satisfy $f(0)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first implication is false.

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\; \; f(x)-x\le 0$$

implies that the function $ g:x\mapsto f(x)-x $ is negative but not necessarily decreasing $(g'(x)=f'(x)-1\le 0 $
Take for example $$f(x)=x-x^2$$
then
$$x>1 \implies f'(x)-1<-2$$

The second is semi true :
In fact, For $ x\ge 0$,

$$(\forall t\in[0,x])\; f'(t)\le 1\implies$$
$$\int_0^xf'(t)dt\le \int_0^xdt$$
$$\implies f(x)-f(0)\le x$$
$$\implies f(x)\le x$$

and for $ x\le 0$
$$\int_x^0f'(t)dt\le \int_x^0dt$$
$$\implies f(x)\ge x$$

Comment: Can you explain why you swapped limits of integration when $x \le 0$ ?

Comment: @OmidSadeghi because if $ f\le g$  then $\int_a^bf\le \int_a^bg $ IF $ a\le b$.

Comment: I think in the first part you should've used $x<0$ when giving the example because then we have $f'(x)-1>0 \implies f'(x)>1$ which shows $f(x)=x-x^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi In the first part, i did not use integration.

Comment: Yes, I know that but in the first part you wanted to give an example function which satisfies $f(x) - x \le 0$ and does not does **not** satisfy $f'(x) - 1 \le 0$.

The example is correct but you incorrectly considered the function when $x > 1$ which gives  $f'(x) - 1 \le -2 \le 0$. 

If you consider the function when $x < 0$ then we have $f'(x) - 1 > 0$

Answer (score 2):

Try $f(x)=\ln (x+1)$.
It can be shown that $f(x)\le x$ but $f'(-0.5)=2>1$